# Can I extract keys based on friendly name using openssl?

Tags: openssl, keystore, pkcs#12

My keystore contains 2 keys, and I would like to run 2 commands which will output each respective key based on alias/`friendlyName`. At the moment the command below outputs both keys to the `TESTKEY.key` file. I have read the openssl docs and tried using `-name` parameter followed by each respective friendly name but it still outputs both keys to the one file. The `winpty` is used for `gitbash`

```
winpty openssl pkcs12 -in KEYSTORE_NAME.p12 -out TESTKEY.key -nodes -nocerts
```

Tried with the `-name` but produces same output:

```
winpty openssl pkcs12 -in KEYSTORE_NAME.p12 -name friendly_name_one -out KEY_ONE.key -nodes -nocerts
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve the problem with openssl, but the Java `keytool` seems to be more powerfull in this regard. The following command exports the Private Key and the respective Certificate. You can play around with it (`keytool -importkeystore --help`)

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /path/to/cert/combined.p12 -srcalias http_ca -destkeystore /path/to/cert/single.p12
```

To get the srcalias use one of the following commands:

```
keytool -list -keystore /path/to/cert/combined.p12
```

or

```
openssl pkcs12 -in /path/to/cert/combined.p12 -info -nodes
```